# Prolog - Add to Total if condition is met

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a Prolog function that does this:

> Takes three parameters: a name, a course list, and an integer.  The integer should be equal to the number of projects in the list that include the name.

**EDIT**

I've cleaned up my code a bit:

```
studentCount(Name, [], 0).
studentCount(Name, [Project|MoreProjects], Sum) :-
    nameInProject(Name, Project),
    studentCount(Name, MoreProjects, Sum),
    NewSum is Sum + 1.
studentCount(Name, [Project|MoreProjects], Sum) :-
    not(nameInProject(Name, Project)),
    studentCount(Name, MoreProjects, Sum).

nameInProject(Name, Name1+Name2+_) :-
    Name == Name1;
    Name == Name2.
```

It binds N to the length of the list, however, every time I call this:

```
?- studentCount(x,[x+y+1,a+b+2,c+x+3],N)
N = 3.
```

Since the atom x is visible in two projects, it should bind N to 2.  Not sure where exactly I should look for for the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should use the following :

```
studentCount(Name, [], 0).
studentCount(Name, [Project|MoreProjects], NewSum) :-
    nameInProject(Name, Project),
    studentCount(Name, MoreProjects, Sum),
    NewSum is Sum + 1.
studentCount(Name, [Project|MoreProjects], Sum) :-
    not(nameInProject(Name, Project)),
    studentCount(Name, MoreProjects, Sum).

% checks if name is in the project
nameInProject(Name, Name1+Name2+_) :-
    Name == Name1;
    Name == Name2.
```

As the NewSum you use to increment Sum is what you need to get at the end.

---

**Edit :**
I don't have a prolog interpreter right now but you could even try the following :

```
studentCount(Name, [], 0).
studentCount(Name, [Project|MoreProjects], NewSum) :-
    nameInProject(Name, Project),
    studentCount(Name, MoreProjects, Sum),
    NewSum is Sum + 1;
    studentCount(Name, MoreProjects, NewSum).

% checks if name is in the project
nameInProject(Name, Name1+Name2+_) :-
    Name == Name1;
    Name == Name2.
```